# Create Card visual in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

do you know how i can create a card visual in Quicksight

like for example in power bi you can create a card visual to display totals

is it possible in Quicksight, ididnt see it on the list of visuals

visual card created like in power bi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.